# Large TextBlock works much faster when placed inside a ViewBox

Tags: wpf

Accidentialy found a strange behaviour. A large TextBlock, containing 100k lines, is rendered very slow, resizing and scrolling it takes about a second. But if this TextBlock is placed within a ViewBox with `Stretch="None"` it is scrolled and resized quite fast.

Something in background is definitely changed with a ViewBox, but what and why?

Window contents

```
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Viewbox Stretch="None">
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind, just creating some text

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine($"Line #{i} ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    }
    this.TextContainer.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Presence of a ScrollView have no effect it is still slow without a ViewBox and fast with it. If I change TextBlock to a TextBox with the same content performance becomes fast in all cases. So it is TextBox specific.

**Little update:** Clarification. I do not need to display large text amounts with a TextBlock, TextBox or [insert whatever you want]. All I want, is to understand, why it behaves like this? Perhaps this knowledge will help me to find solutions to later quiestions, avoid some troubles or just quench my thirst for knowledge. While I appreciate advices on performance optimizations, it does not answer the question.

Comment: TextBlock is not designed to display huge amount of text. It's a highly optimized control with the only purpose to display a single line of text (flow content). You can try to use a FlowDocument rendered using the FlowDocumentScrollViewer control (which is by far not as heavy as the RichTextBox).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `ViewBox`, the layout and the rendering [is done only once](https://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html), then, it's only an *image* that is clipped by the `ScrollViewer`.

Without the `ViewBox`, the layout is recalculated at each change (scroll, resize, ...). Which causes a slowdown. Maybe it's possible do disable some [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls) but I'm not sure.

Comment: The viewbox does not turn it's content into an image. It scales everything inside it. I have apps rely on that fact.

Comment: It was an image, that's why the text is in italics.

Comment: One window displays ~22 lines, whole text - 100k/22 = 4.5k windows. Window size is 800x450, that is 4.5k x 800 x 450 = 1.6GB sized image for one byte per pixel. However running app with a ViewBox use same amount of memory as an app without one (btw, the latter reallocates a lot of memory during scroll/resize). So it doesn't look like a pre-rendered imaged is stored in background.

Comment: @Orace On the linked tutorial page I do not see anything about one-time rendering

Comment: I know it's not an image  If you have related links I will be happy to add them to my answer.